# Solving a Three Variable Equation 3;

Tags: linear-algebra

Today i am facing a problem which involves three variable.
Question: $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{y}+\frac{2}{z}=4$$
$$\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{2}{z}=3$$
$$ \frac{6}{x}+\frac{-4}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=0$$
I know to solve if all three like $ax+by+cz+d=0$ by doing cramer rule.

But i dont how to solve this. Please help me.

Comment: u = 1/x, v=1/y, w = 1/z.  Now you have a linear equation that you know how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{1}{x},b=\frac{1}{y},c=\frac{1}{z}$.  Now you can use Cramer's if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, i got it.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:

Make the change of variables $X = \frac{1}{x}$, $Y = \frac{1}{y}$ and $Z = \frac{1}{z}$.

Solve the new system of equations for $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, and then find $x$, $y$ and $z$.

For example, if $X = -2$ then $-2 = \frac{1}{x}$ and hence $x=-\frac{1}{2}$.